# preg_match(): Unknown modifier php function

Tags: php, function

Function not working it's giving me error

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '_' in /home/u170751922/public_html/include/functions/main.php on line 325
```

Here is my code :

```
function verify_valid_email($emailtocheck)
{
       $eregicheck = "^([-!#\$%&'*+./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~])+@([-!#\$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\$/i";
       return preg_match($eregicheck, $emailtocheck);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've forgotten delimiters:

```
$eregicheck = "/^([-!#\$%&'*+.\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~])+@([-!#\$%&'*+\/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\$/i";
```

-and, also, note, that `/` as a delimiter *must* be escaped in regex itself